# Maximo Outbound interface using webservice to Biztalk/SAP

Tags: biztalk, maximo

We are trying to create an Outbound Interface between Maximo 7.5 with BizTalk.
We have followed all the steps of Creating an Object structure, Endpoint,And Publish Channel.Then associating Publish channel with an external system.
We created a web service from Object Structure and for its deployment we followed :- select Action-> Product Web Service Container->Deploy Web Service. And from that we generated the WSDL file.

But we are receing an error as below

"BMXAA1481E - Could not send.The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."

We are unable to integrate our Maximov7.5 to Biztalk.
Any thoughts around??

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at:

- [WCF Error: The message with Action cannot be processed at the receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714357/wcf-error-the-message-with-action-cannot-be-processed-at-the-receiver)
- [The message with Action '' cannot be processed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671500/the-message-with-action-cannot-be-processed)

N.